# Is $BV$ the dual of a separable Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, bounded-variation

In literature I am reading right now, it says $BV(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open bounded set, is the dual of a separable space. Is it a dual separable Banach space, or not a Banach space at all?

I am asking, because I want to use the weak-* compactness theorem Banach Alaoglu on this space, but then $BV(\Omega)$ needs to be the dual of a separable Banach space.

Answer (score 3):

A late answer: Yes, this is the case. However, this space is no commonly known space. The construction of the pre-dual space and more details can be found in in Remark 3.12 of the book

Ambrosio, Luigi; Fusco, Nicola; Pallara, Diego (2000). *Functions of bounded variation and free discontinuity problems*. Oxford Mathematical Monographs. New York and Oxford: The Clarendon Press/Oxford University Press, New York, pp. xviii+434, ISBN 0-19-850245-1, [MR1857292](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1857292), [Zbl 0957.49001](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0957.49001).